# Why does the compiler infer different lifetimes for a trait and its implementation?

Tags: rust

I'm currently using [rustlearn](https://github.com/maciejkula/rustlearn) to evaluate different classification models. The problem I ran into basically boils down to this:

```
trait Foo<T> {
    fn bar(&self, x: T);
}

struct Baz;

struct Smth;

impl<'a> Foo<&'a Smth> for Baz {
    fn bar(&self, x: &Smth) {}
}

fn main() {
    let some_foo: Box<Baz> = Box::new(Baz {});  // ok
    // let some_foo: Box<Foo<&Smth>> = Box::new(Baz {});  // not ok
    let x = Smth {};
    some_foo.bar(&x);
}
```

While it is possible to type `some_foo` as `Box<Baz>`, it is not possible to use `Box<Foo<&Smth>>` instead, since it will cause the compiler to complain about `&x` being dropped (at the end of `main`) while still borrowed (in `bar`). This is (I think) due to the fact that `x` is created *after* `some_foo`, hence `x` gets dropped *before* `some_foo`.
Moving the creation of `x` such that it occurs before the creation of `some_foo` would be a solution; but let's assume that's not possible¹.

I still don't quite get why the code is valid for `some_foo: Box<Baz>` but not for `some_foo: Box<Foo<&Smth>>`. What is it that the compiler cannot know (otherwise it wouldn't need to complain)?

---

¹ because you have a collection of models which you wish to crossvalidate , i.e. `model.fit(x, y)` where `x, y` are subsets of larger `(X, Y)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boxed trait object needs to work with all lifetimes for the reference to `Smth`:

```
let some_foo: Box<for<'a> Foo<&'a Smth>> = Box::new(Baz {});
```

Maybe someone else can explain why the compiler couldn't derive a working lifetime :)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the for any/all syntax :)

Comment: There are issues with using the *same* lifetime at both type and method level; it causes some kind of "anchoring". I've seen the trick use to make a value immovable for example. In general, whenever this comes up it means there's a design problem.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I thought so, it seemed weird to me to restrict the API like that. But since I just started learning rust, I wasn't quite sure if I was the problem or the API was